# Why not sprite larger images that are page content?

Tags: css, image, css-sprites

The typical rule of thumb when it comes to using CSS sprites for images is that you should only do it for smaller images (like icons) and that actual image content should always be represented through `<img>` elements. **My question is: why?** Aren't the advantages of spriting worthwhile for content images as well?

One reason I have read is to enable the use of `alt` text, to be more syntactically correct and accessible to screen-readers. However, when that is a concern, couldn't you just as easily use a single tiny transparent image with all the syntactical sugar atop a sprite that presents the real visual content?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could, but:

1. Content images don’t tend to be re-used as much as UI-type images like icons. Imagine a newspaper site: if every content image they used in every story was part of a sprite, that sprite would very quickly get huge, and would be downloaded even by users who only looked at one story.
2. Website content is generally expected to be maintained by people who don’t know CSS. It’s a bit unreasonable to expect content editors to edit a master sprite image file, re-save out to a JPG, and pop in some CSS just to put an image on a page.
3. If you sprite a lot of large image files, the sprite file will get really large. It might take an unacceptably long time to download when the user first visits the page, or it might use up too much bandwidth on users who only end up seeing one of the images within the sprite.

Obviously, those are generalisations — in a specific situation, it might make perfect sense to sprite larger/more content-y images.

On using an `<img>` tag with a tiny transparent image file for sprites, you can do that for any sprite images — it’s often useful for clipping and positioning the sprite image beyond what `background-position` allows.

Comment: Nice answer. Great info. One question: you noted that use of the `background-image` property removes the need for the transparent image. I don't see anywhere in the `background-image` property that lets you specify alt-text. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jeffrey: ah, no, using `background-image` on an `<img>` tag doesn’t remove the need for alt text. I’m just saying you can use an `<img>` tag for all your sprite images if you want, not just content-y ones.

Comment: Good call. I was reversing what you meant (thinking you were saying to avoid the `<img>` use I suggested, rather than encourage it :)

Comment: One more: content images are content. Unlike an `<img>` element, background images do not have an `alt` attribute and are not announced by assistive technologies like screen readers.

Comment: @steveax: as the OP said, "One reason I have read is to enable the use of alt text, to be more syntactically correct and accessible to screen-readers. However, when that is a concern, couldn't you just as easily use a single tiny transparent image with all the syntactical sugar atop a sprite that presents the real visual content?" i.e. you can have your sprite as the background of an `<img>` element.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite what if the screenreader user wants to download the "cute kitten" picture and email it to someone else?

Comment: @steveax: then they've just cut themself on a sharp edge case. I think some browsers do have a "View background image" option in their right-click menus, so it's not beyond screen readers to offer similar functionality (although obviously with a sprite background you get several images).

Answer (score 6):

One additional reason I can think of, is search-engines; if you have an image with a descriptive alt-tag or a `figure` element with a `figcaption`, search engines will be able to find, classify and show it.

Comment: Do search engines actually index `alt` text in practice though? Isn’t it too easily spammable?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite Image search seems to work in Google, so I guess they have to but perhaps they compare it with the page content.

Comment: I don]t think Google Image Search relies on alt text. E.g. [this page](http://freakytrigger.co.uk/ft/2007/02/pigs-sausages-in-blankets-bacon-pig-biscuit-dough/) has an alt text-free image of pigs in blankets which comes up first in a Google Image search for “pig in blanket”.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite They have definitely thought about it more than I have just now :-) But I still think image tags with the actual images will work better for image search than no image tags or transparent images with backgrounds.

Comment: @jeroen: heh! I guess they’ve probably spent a bit of time on it. Alt text may indeed have an effect, or could be used in future.

Answer (score 1):

Sprites are usually usefull for static contents (images that are common on many pages).
Content pictures often appears in only one page, so you can't add it to your sprite file.

If you want to have real-time sprite generation, making custom sprite file with all your pictures, I think the generation cost is far more expensive than the duplicated HTTP calls it saves.

Sprites are here to save HTTP requests, but you should not waste server-side computation time to make it, nor put expensive and unusefull pictures in your sprite file.

Comment: Caching is more important than sprites for impacting images on multiple pages vs a single page.

Saving HTTP request overhead is indeed the primary benefit of sprites, but why can't that apply to content-images as well as the more generic site-wide images? Depending on the page, this could still result in a lot of savings! Assume server computation time is a non-issue since the sprites would be generated by the page designer.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a designer to make content-related sprites, as it should be dynamic content. One way of doing it could be an automatic sprite generation during the page-making process (the sprite map would need to be updated with the content). But this makes sens only for pages containing a lot of pictures, and it would not benefit from the cache as much as the classic ui sprite map.

Comment: I'm not looking for cache benefits here. Within reason, those apply regardless of whether you do sprites or do standard images. I'm purely concerned with savings from consolidating a lot of http requests. Talking about applicability of cache is straight up apples and oranges. And declaring that all content images for web pages should be dynamic is way too broad of a statement to make IMO.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that often the person that design and build a website is not the same as the one that puts content in it. As stated by Paul D. Waite "Website content is generally expected to be maintained by people who don’t know CSS". Obviously if this is not your case and you have a page with *lots* of content-related pictures, you can think about spriting these. Also, cache benefits *is* related to sprites use.

Answer (score 1):

Sprites should be used for common icons across the whole website and not for page specific content. When you use sprites for big images you get a lot of white space that is wasted.

According to http://blog.vlad1.com/2009/06/22/to-sprite-or-not-to-sprite/ this is also a problem:

> Another (but much less important) downside is that if a sprite-using
>   page is zoomed using the full-page zoom feature that’s present in many
>   browsers, the browser may need to do extra work to get the correct
>   behaviour at the edges of these images — basically, to avoid adjacent
>   images in the sprite from “leaking in.”  This isn’t a problem for
>   small images, but can be a performance hit for bigger ones.

Comment: I don't buy "use only for site-wide images" with no additional reasoning. That's exactly what I'm questioning here. The reduction in HTTP Requests can still be of benefit on a single page. That said, `+1` for the performance impact info.

Comment: If you have 50k in site wide images and 2MB of page specific content why should you download the 2MB in pages that don't require those images? It's wasted bandwidth

Comment: Right. Clearly you would have a page-specific sprite-map.

Answer (score 1):

From the research I've continued to do on this, another potential issue is memory consumption. Despite the fact that sprites may be compressed enough to download quickly, the footprint they fill in the client machine's memory is after the browser has rendered them, meaning it can be quite large, even for sprites with fairly small file sizes.

I haven't seen a definitive answer on whether or not this memory footprint is any larger than what one would see when loading the same number of images without sprites. I will be testing that in the coming weeks for the project that prompted this question, so I will return and update this answer once I have a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Sprites are used to reduce the amount of requests to a server. The impact of lots of small requests is slowing the server more than one bigger request. But if the image of sprites, I like to call it sprite-map, is too large, it will also slow down the performance. The other thing of importance is like you sad the possibility for each single picture to give some name, to manage and to index by search engine.

Comment: Short of the zooming discussion [mentioned by JSantos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108497/why-not-sprite-larger-images-that-are-page-content/7108650#7108650), how do large sprite-maps slow down performance? Are you aware that [the Mozilla standard sprite-map is 1000x2000 pixels](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/03/27/css-spriting-tips/)?

Comment: They USE a map of 1000x2000 px, but its not a standard or recommended. My maps were never of that size. Big maps increase loading time, processing time and memory usage and then the advantage of sprite-maps gets lost.